# Add hidden form variable to the end of the URL

Tags: javascript, url-parameters

I have searched Unbounce and Google for documentation, but can't find a way to make this work. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Use case:

I have a test page setup in Unbounce and it would be great when a user lands on the page and submits the form that the value being generated through the script below in the hidden field is added to the current URL upon submission.

It's important that if the user lands on the page from an advertising campaign that the value is added to URL and does not replace it.

Example:
User lands on `testpage.com` or `testpage.com?qs=3134728&pcd=THANKS20&dclid=CNi4wvCv39cCFZdFNwodE_wALA`

Unique ID is created with the following JavaScript and added to a hidden field:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var id = new Date().toISOString().replace(/[-tTzZ:.]/g, '');
    $('#lead_id').val(id);
  });
</script>
```

User clicks submit and and is redirected to a thankyou page with the value of the hidden field passed in the URL:

```
testpage.com/thank-you?lead_id=1234
testpage.com/thankyou?qs=3134728&pcd=THANKS20&dclid=CNi4wvCv39cCFZdFNwodE_wALA&lead_id=1234
```

I should also mention that I can not edit the html of the form so this would need to happen with JavaScript as Unbounce provides a space to add custom code.

Answer (score 0):

Is the form method `get`? If it is `post` it wont append that to the URL for the hidden field.

Your approach seems right however if this is the HTML on page:

```
<form action="http://example.com" method="get" id="theForm">
    <input type="hidden" value="xyz" />
    <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

You can use some JS code like one of the following to modify this...however you'll want to verify that everything still works as expected:

```
document.getElementById('theForm').action = "http://another.example.com";

document.getElementById('theForm').method = "get";
```

Comment: Hmmm I can see that is is post.

method="POST"

I can not edit the html of the form in Unbounce, only add custom JS.

Comment: Yeah you'll need to change this to be a `get` or modify the `action`. Edited post above to include some JS